# Display value of specific element from multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please help, how can I display the posts where site_id is `1` from below multidimensional array and display it with comma separated like `4295, 4289, 4298, 4292`

```
print_r($favorites);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [site_id] => 1
            [posts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4295
                    [1] => 4289
                    [2] => 4298
                    [3] => 4292
                )

            [groups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [group_id] => 1
                            [site_id] => 1
                            [group_name] => Default List
                            [posts] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 4295
                                    [1] => 4289
                                    [2] => 4298
                                    [3] => 4292
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: Try `echo $favorites[0]["posts"];`

Comment: Post your php array